# storing full html pages in mysql

Tags: html, mysql

I'm trying to store a full HTML page in a MySQL DB.

This is my DB schema:

[image]

I think this SQL query must do this job:

```
SELECT PC.id, T.name AS tag, HT.name AS attr,
       HTV.content AS attr_val, PC.content, C.Count
FROM page_content AS PC
INNER JOIN page AS P ON PC.page = P.id
INNER JOIN html_tags AS T ON PC.tag = T.id
INNER JOIN html_tag_attr_val AS HTV ON PC.attr = HTV.id
INNER JOIN html_tag_attr AS HT ON HTV.attr = HT.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tag_parrent, COUNT(*) AS Count
           FROM page_content
           GROUP BY tag_parrent) C ON P.id = C.tag_parrent
WHERE P.name = 'index' AND PC.tag_parrent = 0
```

But something went wrong when `attr` column is empty
ex. I have inserted `span` tag without attributes.
This query gives me nothing.

Comment: html is just text. treat it like you would any OTHER text.

Comment: Are... are you trying to make a database representation of the entire tag hierarchy of an HTML page? Why?

Comment: is you issue retrieving records from with sql join or storing plain text? what bit do you have working?

Comment: yes. I`m trying to make a database representation of the entire tag hierarchy of an HTML page. becouse I need to store all pages in mysql and need unique tags and attrs in their places.  I think the error is in query, in joining part. becouse when in attr column is written something query is working well. but if in this column is nothing, query gives me nothing.

Comment: Can you not just use one table: `Page`, with fields of Id, name and content (which stores all your html as the wysiwyg outputs it - keeping the order of your tags too)?

Comment: @shalvasoft Why aren't you just storing the whole HTML as a `TEXT` field? Why break it up into dozens/hundreds/thousands of nested records?

Comment: no I can not do this. I need this structure

Comment: I`m creating application: "html builder" so I need to add this info as it is. So becouse I need this structure of my DB.

Comment: how do you handle the `strong` in this situation `<p>this sentence has <strong>strong tags</strong> and occur <strong>multiple times</strong></p>`  I see no where in your structure that would say where in the parent the child will occur

Comment: p and strong in the tags column and the text in the content column in page_content table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that you've gone to this extreme break-apart/storage of the HTML because you want to use database tools to analyze tag usage in some way?

I'm with Marc B, a database is just not the best way to go about this kind of thing...

If you feel you must, then you'll probably want to use some kind of **pre-parser/validator of the raw HTML** prior to storing it to make sure that the html is well formed and valid, before storing it into a set of relational tables like this.  That will significantly reduce corner case errors.

But like Marc B is saying, since html is ultimately just text, it really is best to store it in your dB as a single text record, then use a program that does the parsing when you want to do the analysis.

Comment: ok. I understand that html is simple text and I can use 1 table for this job. but I need to use tags and attributes as I need. I understand that this way is not best. but I need this structure. after this query I will use my php application for parsing this array. but in this time I have problem in query, in join part where I`m checking attr column info in other table. I do not know hot to write that if column is empty query must not do inner join. I understand that I can break this query in parts and use php to execute them one by one. but I want touse only 1 query instead of 10 query.

Comment: Let me know if there are any similar scheme. And if there is any, can I look at them?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can be chasing corner cases like this all the time.  Basically a tag with a blank attribute shouldn't be considered "valid", so instead of trying to write a query that will take that into account, if you use a pre-parser/validator **befor**e storing into your database, then the "blank attribute" would be removed from the tag, such that what you load into your database will then meet your standard query.  Otherwise, you're going to have to build a lot of "corner case" exceptions into your query(s).

Comment: If you're developing in Java, I can highly recommend the [JSOUP parser](http://jsoup.org/). If you run the original html through this parser/validator, and then load the results into your database, then your query will work.

Comment: May I ask what you're developing in, or what you're using to load your dB?